# Solving 2 equations for a field

Tags: field-theory

I have got a set $ F=\{{0,1,2}\}$ and I know that $(F,+,*)$ is a field.

Now I have to solve the two equations:
$$ 2x+2y= 1$$
$$1x+2y=2$$

By calculating the answer according to the field tables I get $x=-1, y=0$ which is obviously wrong. I can't seem to find where I made the mistakes. Anyone got a right answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your answer is correct.  You simply have to remember that '-1' in this field is whatever number, when added to 1, yields 0.  That is, '-1' is another name for 2.
*[think: 'modular arithmetic']*

Comment: I see, thank you very much! Does that mean I can just do the following when trying to verify the answer: $4

Comment: Oops, accidently hit enter. Well what I wanted to ask is: I understand that -1 is simply a symbol for the additive inverse of 1. But if I had to write it down and have 2 * (-1) = 1, how can I transform the left side to make it match the right side?

Comment: Ahh nevermind, I think I completely understand it now. As -1 does not really exist as an element in my field, so I am just better off writing 2 instead of -1 because they are pretty much equivalent in this case.